# MySQL server Upstart script not working on boot

Tags: server, boot, mysql, upstart, openvz

For some reason the Upstart script for the MySQL server isn't working when I boot my server, however it does work once the server has booted and I execute `sudo start mysql` manually.

I'm running an OpenVZ VPS with Ubuntu 10.04 installed and MySQL version 5.1.41 (latest stable from the repository). MySQL is a fresh install with no config changed.

/etc/init/mysql.conf:

```
# MySQL Service

description     "MySQL Server"
author          "Mario Limonciello <superm1@ubuntu.com>"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
      and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

env HOME=/etc/mysql
umask 007

pre-start script
    #Sanity checks
    [ -r $HOME/my.cnf ]
    [ -d /var/run/mysqld ] || install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld
    # Load AppArmor profile
    if aa-status --enabled 2>/dev/null; then
        apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld || true
    fi
    LC_ALL=C BLOCKSIZE= df --portability /var/lib/mysql/. | tail -n 1 | awk '{ exit ($4<4096) }'
end script

exec /usr/sbin/mysqld

post-start script
    for i in `seq 1 30` ; do
        /usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file="${HOME}"/debian.cnf ping && {
            exec "${HOME}"/debian-start
            # should not reach this line
            exit 2
        }
        sleep 1
    done
    exit 1
end script
```

Comment: What is the output of `runlevel`? What does `/etc/init/mysql.conf` contain at the top? It should read something like `start on (net-device-up and local-filesystems and runlevel [2345])`

Comment: I've added the contents of the /etc/init/mysql.conf file. Also using `/etc/rc*.d` isn't working any more, however manual starting is still working. Where can I get the runlevel output?

Comment: Just run the `runlevel` command. The config looks similar to mine...

Comment: The output of `runlevel` is `N 2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out Upstart start up jobs can have problems on OpenVZ.

Changing:

```
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
      and runlevel [2345])
```

to:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

fixed the problem for me.

Comment: +1, can you maybe also add a link to other accounts of OpenVZ instances having problems w/ upstart? I'm guessing its because there's no filesystems mounting going on, so local-filesystems never gets triggered.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 11.10 with Mediatomb.  Tried it.

Comment: I ended up switching to [Linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=65f866a7004f627ae37fa3283f8a89b4fa9cecbe) because they use Xen servers, due to the numerous problems I was having with OpenVZ like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the upstart scripts with a simple GUI tool named [jobs-admin](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jobs-admin). You can install it by typing `sudo apt-get install jobs-admin` in a terminal.

Once installed you can manage all upstart scripts including MySQL using this tool.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see how a GUI tool will help me on Ubuntu Server...

Comment: This gui , version 0.8.0 didnt work for me on Ubuntu 11.10.  I think it is too buggy still.